# How do i fix the size of css border?

Tags: html, css

I am learning html, css and javascript myself, using online tutorials. The css border next to bbc logo is too short. Please tell me why.

Browser:

[image]

Code: http://pastebin.com/FWrs084N
(this code will always be there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your padding was slightly off. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prytq0qy/1/)

Basically change the property of `logodiv` from

```
padding-top: 7px;
```

to

```
padding: 6px 80px 12px 20px
```

To avoid this in the future, you would ideally add a class name which would have the same properties, that way the elements get the consistent styles.

Comment: signindiv is already  padding: 6px 80px 12px 20px; not sure what to change.

Comment: Hmmm. I meant `logodiv` - sorry - check the fiddle you will know what i am talking about.

Comment: np. now, the border is spilling out of the red topbar.

Comment: Did you try reducing the padding: `6px 80px 10px 20px` to see if it works ?

Comment: the border size reduces a bit, but the BBC logo also moves up. I want the bbc logo to be centered. FIXED -  #logodiv{
  padding: 8px 10px 4px 20px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 5px solid #DA4C4C;
 }

Comment: Main question - what was my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  font-family: Helmet,Freesans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

#topbar{
  background-color: #CC0101;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.fixedwidth{
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}              
#logodiv{
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 5px solid #DA4C4C;
}
#signindiv{
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 80px 0 20px;
  font-size: 0.9em;       
  border-right: 5px solid #DA4C4C;
}
#topmenudiv ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
} 
#topmenudiv li{
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-right: 5px solid #DA4C4C;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px 8px 20px;
}
.fixedwidth > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="topbar">

    <div class="fixedwidth">

      <div id="logodiv">
        <img src="images/logo.png"/>
      </div>

      <div id="signindiv">
        <img src="images/signin.png"/> Sign in
      </div>

      <div id="topmenudiv">
        <ul>
          <li>News</li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Comment: please remove the extra code and paste only the fixes.

Comment: I replaced all float: left; to display: inline-block; and added vertical-align: middle; to centered all elements. Removed all padding-top and padding-bottom too; (vertical-align do it for us)